# How to remove sublist from a list based on indices in another list?

Tags: python, list

I have these lists:

```
ls = [[0, "a"],
      [2, "c"]]

ls2 = [[0, "a"],
       [1, "b"],
       [2, "c"],
       [3, "d"],
       [4, "e"]]
```

I want to remove all sublists from `ls2` that are not in `ls`. So at the end `ls2` should be the same as `ls`. I tried this:

```
ls = [[0, "a"],
      [2, "c"]]

ls2 = [[0, "a"],
       [1, "b"],
       [2, "c"],
       [3, "d"],
       [4, "e"]]

indices_left = [l[0] for l in ls]

for subll in ls2:
    if subll[0] not in indices_left:
        ls2.pop(subll[0])

for subll2 in ls2:
    print(subll2)
```

But this gives:

```
[0, 'a']
[2, 'c']
[3, 'd']
```

I think this is because the first for loop removes list `[1, "b"]` but after that list `[2, "c"]` moves to `ls2[1]` and list `[3, "d"]` moves to `ls2[2]` and since `ls[1][0] == 2`, sublist `[3, "d"]` is not removed because it is now at index `ls2[2]`. How can I avoid this and remove all sublists from `ls2` that are not in `ls`?

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact that there's no use for your code because if you want `ls2` to be identical to `ls` you could just copy it, the following list comprehension will work:

```
ls = [[0, "a"],
      [2, "c"]]

ls2 = [[0, "a"],
       [1, "b"],
       [2, "c"],
       [3, "d"],
       [4, "e"]]
ls2 = [x for x in ls2 if x in ls]
```

### Edit

If the goal is to select only elements from `ls2` that have the same first element as an item from `ls`, then this will work:

```
indices = [x[0] for x in ls]
ls2 = [x for x in ls2 if x[0] in indices]
```

Comment: If I understood OP correctly, it's not strict equality, but rather index equality. If `ls = [[0, 'b'], [2, 'd]]` then `ls2` should be `[[0, 'a'], [2, 'c']]`.

Comment: Hi, my examples for ls and ls2 were bad, but in reality other elements in ls could be different, for example: ls = [[0, "x"], [2, []]]

Comment: @HenryEcker Good catch, I've edited accordingly

Comment: @Programmer Does the edit now answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension.

```
ls = [[0, "a"],
      [2, "c"]]

ls2 = [[0, "a"],
       [1, "b"],
       [2, "c"],
       [3, "d"],
       [4, "e"]]
ls2 = [x for x in ls2 if x in ls]

        

print(ls2)
```